# How can I parse the IO String in Haskell?

Tags: string, parsing, haskell, io, monads

I' ve got a problem with Haskell. I have text file looking like this:

```
5.
7. 
[(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9),(10,11,12)].
```

I haven't any idea how can I get the first 2 numbers (2 and 7 above) and the list from the last line. There are dots on the end of each line.

I tried to build a parser, but function called 'readFile' return the Monad called IO String. I don't know how can I get information from that type of string.

I prefer work on a array of chars. Maybe there is a function which can convert from 'IO String' to [Char]?

Comment: Note that String is just a type alias for [Char], so the only thing standing between you and a [Char] is the IO (which you can not get rid of - you need to work inside the IO monad (see any monad tutorial for more information)). Also note that [Char] is a (linked) list of chars, not an array.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding about IO in Haskell. Particularly, you say this:

> Maybe there is a function which can convert from 'IO String' to [Char]?

No, there isn't<sup>1</sup>, and the fact that there is no such function is one of the most important things about Haskell.

Haskell is a very principled language. It tries to maintain a distinction between "pure" functions (which don't have any side-effects, and always return the same result when give the same input) and "impure" functions (which have side effects like reading from files, printing to the screen, writing to disk etc). The rules are:

1. You can use a pure function anywhere (in other pure functions, or in impure functions)
2. You can only use impure functions inside other impure functions.

The way that code is marked as pure or impure is using the type system. When you see a function signature like

```
digitToInt :: String -> Int
```

you know that this function is pure. If you give it a `String` it will return an `Int` and moreover *it will always return the same `Int` if you give it the same `String`*. On the other hand, a function signature like

```
getLine :: IO String
```

is *impure*, because the return type of `String` is marked with `IO`. Obviously `getLine` (which reads a line of user input) will not always return the same `String`, because it depends on what the user types in. You can't use this function in pure code, because adding even the smallest bit of impurity will pollute the pure code. Once you go `IO` you can never go back.

You can think of `IO` as a wrapper. When you see a particular type, for example, `x :: IO String`, you should interpret that to mean "`x` is an action that, when performed, does some arbitrary I/O and then returns something of type `String`" (note that in Haskell, `String` and `[Char]` are exactly the same thing).

So how do you ever get access to the values from an `IO` action? Fortunately, the type of the function `main` is `IO ()` (it's an action that does some I/O and returns `()`, which is the same as returning nothing). So you can always use your `IO` functions inside `main`. When you execute a Haskell program, what you are doing is running the `main` function, which causes all the I/O in the program definition to actually be executed - for example, you can read and write from files, ask the user for input, write to stdout etc etc.

You can think of structuring a Haskell program like this:

- All code that does I/O gets the `IO` tag (basically, you put it in a `do` block)
- Code that doesn't need to perform I/O doesn't need to be in a `do` block - these are the "pure" functions.
- Your `main` function sequences together the I/O actions you've defined in an order that makes the program do what you want it to do (interspersed with the pure functions wherever you like).
- When you run `main`, you cause all of those I/O actions to be executed.

---

So, given all that, how do you write your program? Well, the function

```
readFile :: FilePath -> IO String
```

reads a file as a `String`. So we can use that to get the contents of the file. The function

```
lines:: String -> [String]
```

splits a `String` on newlines, so now you have a list of `String`s, each corresponding to one line of the file. The function

```
init :: [a] -> [a]
```

Drops the last element from a list (this will get rid of the final `.` on each line). The function

```
read :: (Read a) => String -> a
```

takes a `String` and turns it into an arbitrary Haskell data type, such as `Int` or `Bool`. Combining these functions sensibly will give you your program.

Note that the only time you actually need to do any I/O is when you are reading the file. Therefore that is the only part of the program that needs to use the `IO` tag. The rest of the program can be written "purely".

It sounds like what you need is the article [The IO Monad For People Who Simply Don't Care](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2007/11/io-monad-for-people-who-simply-dont.html), which should explain a lot of your questions. Don't be scared by the term "monad" - you don't need to understand what a monad is to write Haskell programs (notice that this paragraph is the only one in my answer that uses the word "monad", although admittedly I have used it four times now...)

---

Here's the program that (I think) you want to write

```
run :: IO (Int, Int, [(Int,Int,Int)])
run = do
  contents <- readFile "text.txt"   -- use '<-' here so that 'contents' is a String
  let [a,b,c] = lines contents      -- split on newlines
  let firstLine  = read (init a)    -- 'init' drops the trailing period
  let secondLine = read (init b)    
  let thirdLine  = read (init c)    -- this reads a list of Int-tuples
  return (firstLine, secondLine, thirdLine)
```

To answer `npfedwards` comment about applying `lines` to the output of `readFile text.txt`, you need to realize that `readFile text.txt` gives you an `IO String`, and it's only when you bind it to a variable (using `contents <-`) that you get access to the underlying `String`, so that you can apply `lines` to it.

Remember: once you go `IO`, you never go back.

---

<sup>1</sup> I am deliberately ignoring `unsafePerformIO` because, as implied by the name, it is very unsafe! Don't ever use it unless you *really* know what you are doing.

Comment: I feel like we shouldn't even mention *the function who shall not be named* in these kinds of answers, if only because some students of Haskell might see it, look at the type definition and simply say "*aha! This is what I was after all along!*"

Comment: Isn't it that even if you keep pure functions and functions in the IO monad apart meticuolously the compiler will inline it anyways somehow?

Comment: I get a type error when trying to apply `lines` to the output of `readFile`

Comment: @npfedwards Cool. Remember that `let` is just a way to temporarily give names to things. The only complicated thing I did was in the line `let [a,b,c] = lines contents`. Here I knew that the result of `lines contents` was going to be a list of three elements, so I took advantage of that to call the three elements `a`, `b` and `c`.

Comment: Why can I not give a permanent name to it... ie, without the let?

Comment: What do you mean by a "permanent" name? Where do you want to access the variable, other than inside this `do` block?

Answer (score 13):

As a programming noob, I too was confused by `IO`s. Just remember that if you go `IO` you never come out. Chris wrote a [great explanation on why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229854/how-can-i-parse-the-io-string-in-haskell/11230235#11230235). I just thought it might help to give some examples on how to use `IO String` in a monad. I'll use [getLine](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:getLine) which reads user input and returns an `IO String`.

```
line <- getLine
```

All this does is bind the user input from `getLine` to a value named `line`. If you type this this in ghci, and type `:type line` it will return:

```
:type line
line :: String
```

But wait! `getLine` returns an `IO String`

```
:type getLine
getLine :: IO String
```

So what happened to the `IO`ness from `getLine`? `<-` is what happened. `<-` is your `IO` friend. It allows you to bring out the value that is tainted by the `IO` within a monad and use it with your normal functions. Monads are easily identified because they begin with `do`. Like so:

```
main = do
    putStrLn "How much do you love Haskell?"
    amount <- getLine
    putStrln ("You love Haskell this much: " ++ amount)
```

If you're like me, you'll soon discover that `liftIO` is your next best monad friend, and that `$` help reduce the number of parenthesis you need to write.

So how do you get the information from `readFile`? Well if `readFile`'s output is `IO String` like so:

```
:type readFile
readFile :: FilePath -> IO String
```

Then all you need is your friendly `<-`:

```
 yourdata <- readFile "samplefile.txt"
```

Now if type that in ghci and check the type of `yourdata` you'll notice it's a simple `String`.

```
:type yourdata
text :: String
```

Comment: is there  a de-sugared version of `amount <- getLine` ??

Comment: @matthias `getLine >>= (\amount -> ...)`.

Answer (score 9):

As people already say, if you have two functions, one is `readStringFromFile :: FilePath -> IO String`, and another is `doTheRightThingWithString :: String -> Something`, then you don't really need to escape a string from `IO`, since you can combine this two functions in various ways:

With `fmap` for `IO` (`IO` is `Functor`):

```
fmap doTheRightThingWithString readStringFromFile
```

With `(<$>)` for `IO` (`IO` is `Applicative` and `(<$>) == fmap`):

```
import Control.Applicative

...

doTheRightThingWithString <$> readStringFromFile
```

With `liftM` for `IO` (`liftM == fmap`):

```
import Control.Monad

...

liftM doTheRightThingWithString readStringFromFile
```

With `(>>=)` for `IO` (`IO` is `Monad`, `fmap == (<$>) == liftM == \f m -> m >>= return . f`):

```
readStringFromFile >>= \string -> return (doTheRightThingWithString string)
readStringFromFile >>= \string -> return $ doTheRightThingWithString string
readStringFromFile >>= return . doTheRightThingWithString
return . doTheRightThingWithString =<< readStringFromFile
```

With `do` notation:

```
do
  ...
  string <- readStringFromFile
  -- ^ you escape String from IO but only inside this do-block
  let result = doTheRightThingWithString string
  ...
  return result
```

Every time you will get `IO Something`.

Why you would want to do it like that? Well, with this you will have *pure* and 
*[referentially transparent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency_%28computer_science%29)* programs (functions) in your language. This means that every function which type is IO-free is *pure* and *referentially transparent*, so that for the same arguments it will returns the same values. For example, `doTheRightThingWithString` would return the same `Something` for the same `String`. However `readStringFromFile` which is not IO-free can return different strings every time (because file can change), so that you can't escape such unpure value from `IO`.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a parser of this type:

```
myParser :: String -> Foo
```

and you read the file using

```
readFile "thisfile.txt"
```

then you can read and parse the file using

```
fmap myParser (readFile "thisfile.txt")
```

The result of that will have type `IO Foo`.

The `fmap` means `myParser` runs "inside" the IO.

Another way to think of it is that whereas `myParser :: String -> Foo`, `fmap myParser :: IO String -> IO Foo`.