# Write a function from IO a -> a?

Tags: haskell, io-monad

Take the function `getLine` - it has the type:

```
getLine :: IO String
```

How do I extract the `String` from this `IO` action?

---

More generally, how do I convert this:

```
IO a
```

to this:

```
a
```

If this is not possible, then why can't I do it?

Comment: Because if you could do this, there'd be no point in having an IO type in the first place.

Comment: Would-be duplicate: [*How can I parse the IO String in Haskell?*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11229854/2751851) (I'm not closing this myself because it might make for a better duplicate target).

Comment: Possible duplicate of  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154518/unwrapping-a-monad .

Answer (score 10):

In Haskell, when you want to work with a value that is "trapped" in `IO`, you don't take the value out of `IO`. Instead, you put the operation you want to perform into `IO`, as well!

For example, suppose you want to check how many characters the `getLine :: IO String` will produce, using the `length` function from Prelude.

There exists a helper function called [`fmap`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/The_Functor_class) which, when specialized to `IO`, has the type:

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> IO a -> IO b
```

It takes a function that works on "pure" values not trapped in `IO`, and gives you a function that works with values that are trapped in `IO`. This means that the code

```
fmap length getLine :: IO Int
```

represents an `IO` action that reads a line from console and then gives you its length.

`<$>` is an infix synonym for `fmap` that can make things simpler. This is equivalent to the above code:

```
length <$> getLine
```

Now, sometimes the operation you want to perform with the `IO`-trapped value *itself* returns an `IO`-trapped value. Simple example: you wan to write back the string you have just read using `putStrLn :: String -> IO ()`.

In that case, `fmap` is not enough. You need to use the [`(>>=)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:-62--62--61-) operator, which, when specialiced to `IO`, has the type `IO a -> (a -> IO b) -> IO b`. In out case:

```
getLine >>= putStrLn :: IO ()
```

Using `(>>=)` to chain `IO` actions has an imperative, sequential flavor. There is a kind of syntactic sugar called ["do-notation"](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_notation) which helps to write sequential operation like these in a more natural way:

```
do line <- getLine
   putStrLn line
```

Notice that the `<-` here is not an operator, but part of the syntactic sugar provided by the do notation.

Comment: Great simple explanation for this common question!  "Instead, you put the operation you want to perform into IO, as well!"

Answer (score 2):

Not going into any details, if you're in a `do` block, you can (informally/inaccurately) consider `<-` as getting the value out of the IO.

For example, the following function takes a line from `getLine`, and passes it to a pure function that just takes a String

```
main = do
  line <- getLine
  putStrLn (wrap line)

wrap :: String -> String
wrap line = "'" ++ line ++ "'"
```

If you compile this as `wrap`, and on the command line run

```
echo "Hello" | wrap
```

you should see

```
'Hello'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know C then consider the question "How can I get the string from `gets`?"  An `IO String` is not some string that's made hard to get to, it's a procedure that can return a string - like reading from a network or stdin.  You want to *run* the procedure to obtain a string.

A common way to run IO actions in a sequence is `do` notation:

```
main = do
   someString <- getLine
   -- someString :: String
   print someString
```

In the above you run the `getLine` operation to obtain a `String` value then use the value however you wish.

Answer (score 0):

So "generally", it's unclear why you think you need a function of this type and in this case it makes all the difference.

It should be noted for completeness that it is possible. There indeed exists a function of type `IO a -> a` in the base library called [`unsafePerformIO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/System-IO-Unsafe.html).

But the `unsafe` part is there for a reason. There are few situations where its usage would be considered justified. It's an escape hatch to be used with great caution - most of the time you will let monsters in instead of letting yourself out.

Why can't you normally go from `IO a` to `a`? Well at the very least it allows you to break the rules by having a seemingly pure function that is not pure at all - ouch! If it were a common practice to do this the type signatures and all the work done by the compiler to verify them would make no sense at all. All the correctness guarantees would go out of the window.

Haskell is, partly, interesting precisely because this is (normally) impossible.

For how to approach your `getLine` problem in particular see the other answers.